# Custom Django forms within template and hidden inputs

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Very, very quick question. I'm rendering my own custom forms within my html template...how would I go about submitting the hidden input when the user submits that form?

template.html

```
<form class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action=".">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="four">Your Text</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ comment_form.content.name }}" {% if comment_form.content.value %}value="{{ comment_form.content.value }}"{% endif %} placeholder="" required="required" id="four"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit Comment</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content_type = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    object_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    #parent_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('content',)
```

Comment: Where is your views.py code? Add your views.py code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this part to you  forms.py file (in CommentForm class) :

```
    hidden_field=forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

I hope it will work.let me know